# how to know the amount of possible variations i can have in a randomly generated list of 1s ad 0s

Tags: python, math

i have this code:

```
import random


# create a function that takes the current player and the amount of empty squares on the board
# then create a mapping of 1s and 0s to resemble all possible combinations in a game of connect4
# take into account that the current player has to be always first and that the signs need to be placed randomly every iteration

all_possible_combinations = []

def create_all_combinations(current_player, empty_squares):
    second_player = 0
    combination_count = 0

    if current_player == "X":
        second_player = "O"
    else:
        second_player = "X"

    while combination_count < 100:

        current_comb = [0]*empty_squares

        randomPos1 = random.randint(0, empty_squares-1)
        current_comb[randomPos1] = current_player

        for x in range(empty_squares-1):

            randomPos = random.randint(0, empty_squares-1)

            while current_comb[randomPos] != 0:
                randomPos = random.randint(0, empty_squares-1)

            current_comb[randomPos] = second_player

            if x != empty_squares-2:
                if second_player == "X":
                    second_player = "O"
                else:
                    second_player = "X"

        if current_comb not in all_possible_combinations:
            all_possible_combinations.append(current_comb)
            print(current_comb, randomPos1)

        combination_count += 1
    print(len(all_possible_combinations))

create_all_combinations("O", 4)
```

it basically creates a sort of map for all possible combinations that can be fitted on a connect4 board its purpose is to detect when the board is a tie (no more possible winning scenarios) the code itself works it generates all the combinations taking into account the rules of the game and the current player (as said in the comments present in the code) my question is in the loop where I run 100 times to cover 100 combinations what can I do to minimize that number, in other words, how can I calculate the number of combinations of 1s and 0s that can be generated according to the rules of the game and use that to run through the loop as not to waste efficiency and needlessly run through the code more times then needed.

Comment: Please edit that last long sentence, and break it into smaller phrases.

Comment: A move in Connect4 cannot be made in any arbitrary cell.  There's only the 7 columns.  Gravity pulls the chip to the bottom of the column.

Comment: yes, but if for instance, the top row of the board is clear then the program will create all possible combinations for the row and fit the X, and O values into it. this is the way I thought about it. am I missing something?

Comment: The second player can play on top of the previous player's move, and so it is not at all a requirement that a given "row" needs alternating moves.

Comment: how would you suggest I go about simulating it?

Comment: You don't. There are too many possibilities in general. You need a completely different approach. Currently your question seems to be *"what can I do to minimize that number?"*, but there is no way to do that. You cannot even trust a sample of random moves to detect a potential win, as it just might not be among the sample. You need a different approach that does not do random sampling at all.

Comment: You're right I get your point thanks for the help ill rethink this.

Comment: n binary values can have 2^n combinations